# When I use an Android device, how can I know whether the current page is running in a browser or in captive portal, only by Javascript methods

Tags: javascript, android, wifi, captiveportal

in iOS, if page is running in captive, "safari" will not in appear userAgent.

But in android devices, how can I judge it? localStorage and FetchApi are supported in some android system , we can no longer judge by them.

Judging from "Verison" fields of userAgent is perhaps inaccurate

Comment: Short answer: you can't. A better approach to do whatever you're trying to achieve is to use graceful degradation using [Feature Detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Feature_detection)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.